# How to host the web service in cloud server?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have created one web service in java using eclipse,i need to know how to host that service on cloud server,can any one let me know how to host that service on the cloud,with steps?

Thanks for your precious time!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a http://serverfault.com question, likely to be closed. But here are the pointers,

1. Get an account from Cloud service providers like AWS.,
2. Run a (virtual) machine of your choice,
3. Use ssh/rdc to connect and install all the software that you need,
4. Copy your software/application there.
5. Start your service. Test if the works when you access using public IP/DNS.
6. Get a Domain name -- create an A Name record for the domain using this machine's IP.

Use this domain for accessing your app/service.

Do not forget to take-backup/create-image of your machine.

PS: this was a comment, then I realized it stretched too long.